# How can I get a link to a specific email thread in Gmail if I have the preview pane enabled?

Tags: gmail

I often like to create links to specific email threads and put them in my calendar so that I have the relevant information at my fingertips.

Ever since I enabled the preview pane, this has been impossible.

Does anyone know how I can get it?

Maybe some button I have to press or perhaps even a userscript that I can use with TamperMonkey?

Comment: I don't use the preview pane with Gmail, so I'm not sure if this will work... If you `"shift-click"` the email in the Inbox list, it should open the message in a new window. You should be able to grab the URL of that window to get  a direct link to that message.

Comment: I tried that. The URL does not work.

Comment: This work? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/how-do-i-save-a-link-to-an-email-in-gmail

Comment: I am looking for a way to access the email from a calendar item. I don't like to label and star things because i just need it for one it two things and that feels too disorganized.

Comment: This seems like a totally basic function for email and I can't believe it's taken me this long to notice that it's broken.  I can't function without the preview pane and it's way too much of a pain in the ass to disable it just to get a URL.

Comment: Duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45853/9617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a major kludge, but will do the trick.  First install the bookmarklet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691400/403455).

```
javascript:window.location="https://gmail.com/#search/rfc822msgid:"+encodeURIComponent(window.document.body.innerHTML.match(/Message-ID: &lt;(.*)&gt;/)[1])+"/"+encodeURIComponent(window.location.search.toString().slice(1).split('&').filter(function(x){return x.slice(0,3) == "th="})[0].slice(3));
```

Then follow these instructions.

1. Click the **menu button** to the right of the message's "reply-to" button and select **Show original.**
   [image]
2. After the message's raw source is shown on a new tab (it will resemble the below screenshot), click the bookmarklet.
   [image]
3. A new tab will now open with the regualrly formatted message.  You can now bookmark or copy the message's URL.

Comment: No longer works. Gmail changed something on us, again.